# How to get file upload progress?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, admin-on-rest

I am new to AOR and redux-sagas and I am currently working on a list view drag-and-drop and upload capability. I want the user to be able to drag and drop files and see current upload progress and status from the List view.

The prototype of the component looks like this:

```
// ...
<Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop} onDragLeave={this.onDragLeave} onDragEnter={this.onDragEnter} ref={(node) => {this.dropzoneRef = node;}} disableClick disablePreview style={{}}>
    // Dropped files will appear here, with the upload progress
    <Card style={{marginBottom: "1em"}}>
        <CardTitle>Picture.jpg</CardTitle>
        <CardText>
             // The progress bar will show the upload progress
             <LinearProgress value={50} mode="determinate" />
        </CardText>
    </Card>
    <List {...props} actions={<FileActions onUploadClick={() => {this.dropzoneRef.open()}} />}>
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="name" />
            <DateField source="createdAt" />
            <EditButton />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
</Dropzone>
```

the `onDrop` callback receives the dropped files, and that's where the upload needs to be handled. That's where I am bit puzzled about how I should handle the problem.

I [understand I have to decorate my REST client in order to be able to upload my files](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#decorating-your-rest-client-example-of-file-upload). But how can I plug some functions in order to send the upload progress of each files to my component?

Comment: This is a general file upload related question. You should add the React and Redux tag to get a bigger audience for your question

Comment: AOR uses `fetch` which [does not support upload progress](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/89).